# Android move items with acceleration

Tags: android, gesture

I cant seem to find the answer to this, mainly because I don't know what it is called.

I am going to expand a few features in my app, currently users can touch and drag to move forward in a list of images. What I want is for the users to "swipe" there finger and then all of these images will move under acceleration and will slowly come to a stop.

Is this a gesture? If so is it the "Fling" gesture?

Comment: Does the ListView not do this automatically for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do so.

1. Use `ListView`
2. Use `Gallery`
3. Use `ScrollView`
4. Use `HorizontalScrollView`
5. Write your custom `ViewGroup` or `View`

For the last approach, you have to detect the Fling gesture as you said and handle all the scrolling animations involved.